# PostgreSQL code reaching beyond EXISTS operator even for negation condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbt

for the below code, I have deleted the hist.game_hist table from db.
Now, according to the code below, I want my code to pickup the else condition and avoid going into the then condition (as game_hist does not exists, it will throw error).

But Till now, when I try to run this code, I get the error that, from then condition "hist.game_hist does not exists".

```
SELECT
    pi.*
FROM stg.stg_game pi

WHERE pi.status != '9'

AND pi.hvr_capture_timestamp::timestamp >
    (CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM information_schema.tables
            WHERE table_schema = 'hist' AND table_name = 'game_hist'
        )
        THEN COALESCE(
            (SELECT max(dbt_updated_at) - INTERVAL '120 minutes' FROM hist.game_hist),
            '1900-01-01'::timestamp
        )
        ELSE '1900-01-01'::timestamp
    end)
```

for the above code, I have deleted the hist.game_hist table from db.
Now, according to the code below, I want my code to pickup the else condition and avoid going into the then condition (as game_hist does not exists, it will throw error).

But Till now, when I try to run this code, I get the error that, from then condition "hist.game_hist does not exists".

Comment: The problem is a bit unclear. Add sample table data and also the expected result - all as properly formatted text (no images, no links.) I.e. provide a [mcve].

Comment: You misunderstand when the exception occurs. Keep in mind that SQL is not an imperative language (one that describes _how_ to achieve the result), it is a declarative language (it  desribes _what_ the result should be). The `does not exist` exception is occurring when the query is evaluated, not as any particular expression is executed. All referenced elements must exist prior to the query's execution. Don't read the query as sequential steps.

Comment: But, the concept is to check if the table exists and execute the coalese only if table exists, Is there a way to achieve this without getting the error

Comment: @JohnH Even almost all imperative languages require a statement to compile before it will be executed.

Comment: The real question is why you have a question as to whether a table exists. Why isn't your schema fixed?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing comes from the database's attempt to assess the subquery in the THEN condition even when table doesn't exist. You can conditionally run the subquery only if the table exists by using dynamic SQL to prevent this.
Try this updated code. This code conditionally executes the subquery only if the table exists using a PL/pgSQL block with dynamic SQL. It immediately sets max_dbt_updated_at to the default value if the table is not found, preventing the issue you were experiencing.

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE
    table_exists BOOLEAN;
    max_dbt_updated_at TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
    -- Check if the table exists
    SELECT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_schema = 'hist' AND table_name = 'game_hist'
    ) INTO table_exists;

    -- Use dynamic SQL to conditionally execute the subquery
    IF table_exists THEN
        EXECUTE 'SELECT COALESCE(max(dbt_updated_at) - INTERVAL ''120 minutes'', ''1900-01-01''::timestamp) FROM hist.game_hist'
        INTO max_dbt_updated_at;
    ELSE
        max_dbt_updated_at := '1900-01-01'::timestamp;
    END IF;

    -- Your main query
    SELECT
        pi.*
    FROM stg.stg_game pi
    WHERE pi.status != '9'
    AND pi.hvr_capture_timestamp::timestamp > max_dbt_updated_at;

END $$;
```

Hope it's helpful :)

Comment: The final query will raise an exception, `query has no destination for result data`. Anonymous PL/pgSQL blocks don't return results; however, the block could be made into a function that returns the final query results. Consider renaming `max_dbt_updated_at` to reflect its purpose instead of its source, and refactor the code so that its default value is only defined once.

Answer (score 0):

The following query produces the desired results the OP described:

```
SELECT pi.*
  FROM stg.stg_game pi
  WHERE pi.status != '9'
    AND pi.hvr_capture_timestamp::timestamp > 
        COALESCE((SELECT (XPATH('/table/row/earliest_ts/text()',
                                QUERY_TO_XML(FORMAT($$SELECT MAX(dbt_updated_at) - INTERVAL '120' MINUTE AS earliest_ts FROM %1$I.%2$I$$,
                                                    ist.table_schema,
                                                    ist.table_name),
                                             FALSE,
                                             FALSE,
                                             '')))[1]::text::timestamp
                    FROM information_schema.tables ist
                   WHERE ist.table_schema = 'hist'
                     AND ist.table_name = 'game_hist'), '1900-01-01'::timestamp);
```

This approach takes advantage of `QUERY_TO_XML`'s ability to execute dynamic SQL. Because it is a SQL query instead of a PL/pgSQL anonymous block, it can be used directly as part of a larger SQL query. If `hist.game_hist` doesn't exist, then the SELECT list in the `infromation_schema.tables` subquery is not evaluated, and the subquery returns `NULL`. This query also avoids repeating the default value for the capture timestamp comparison.